# Setup and Conncect Apache Derby Embedded Database (Java, IntelliJ)

Tags: java, database, intellij-idea, derby

I want to create a java application that I can compile and ship to some friends to use.
To store and manage data I need an integrated database so that when my friends and I run the application we can use it to add and work with data that persists between runs. But I also don't want to set up a cloud database/application to connect to, because this would then require a server setup and cost etc.

Now, my problem is, I downloaded the
java jdk-21 (https://www.oracle.com/de/java/technologies/downloads/) and the
db-derby-10.17.1.0-bin.zip (https://db.apache.org/derby/releases/release-10_17_1_0.cgi).
I extracted the content of the derby database into a db folder inside the jdk-21 as it was shown in a tutorial ([See this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fA1ZU.png)).
But I also tried to put it into another folder like a C:\DerbyDB. Which made no difference to the problems I'm facing.

I also added the DERBY_HOME systemvariable path to the db folder and the JAVA_HOME path to the jdk-21 folder.

Then I opened my java application in IntelliJ Ultimate IDE and opened the Data Sources and Drivers window.
I tried to set up the driver and here the first problem occured. Intellij only allowed me to configure the vers. 10.16.1.1 driver, not the vers. 10.17.1.1 one. [Screenshot of Drivers window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0Jvw.png)
Then I tried to set up the conncection with the path to the db a username, connection type default and embedded driver. When I hit "Test Connection" I got two different errors depending on  wheather the checkbox "Create Database" is checked or unchecked.

When checked I get a "database already exists" error: [Screenshot of error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VW345.png)

When unchecked I get a "database not found" error: [Screenshot of error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yiguj.png)

Also: the loading circle next to "test connection" never finishes. I don't get a success or failed message from the IDE. The connection test continues to be in progress endlessly.